# New users should be able to comment in order to contribute

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

Here are some of my observations:

- many new users are often technically strong enough to contribute.
- new users are often "forced" to use an answer as the only way of contributing.

I believe injustice is done to the technically strong and motivated new users.

So a possible solution could be: (Numbers with prepended `~` are up to optimization and discussion)

- Allow new users to comment.
- Only experienced users (rep > ~`1000` from answering) can see the comment first, no one else can.
- Experienced users can upvote, downvote the comment.

  1. If a comment gets a Netto of ~`-2` the comment could be considered spam
     and the **50 rep rule** should be applied to the new user.
  2. If a comment gets a Netto of ~`+2` the comment could be considered valuable and becomes visible to the world. The new user can now continue to contribute.
- If the new user's comments get accepted ~5 times, his comments can be seen by the world directly. However, they should still be open for voting until **rep 50** is reached.

---

- We cannot prevent users from posting spam on the site. (They can always use the answer for this.)
- We can maximize the contribution by giving the technically strong new users a shot.

Comment: Such requests are often made here, always in vain. The bottom line for all of them is something like "if someone is really good and with good intentions, gaining 50 rep isn't that hard".

Comment: yes, eventually they will have 50 rep.

Comment: @AndreElrico “Eventually” is perhaps too strong a word here. Someone who wants 50 rep can earn it in a day. It is almost a certainty within a week for someone who *does* want to participate and who *is* technically strong. Not commenting is more of a barrier to those who lack one or the other of those characteristics. My [very first answer ever](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5433215/2562182), which I did as an unregistered user (later merged with an account I created 2 years after that answer) earned 50 rep. For suggesting one tiny change to OP’s code and a paragraph of prose.

Comment: "many new users are often technically strong enough to contribute" - I'm not sure I agree with this, based on the average question quality (which typically implies a lack of either site or technical knowledge, or both, and in neither case can we really expect them to know what type of comments are appropriate). As it stands, many inappropriate answers are along the lines of "I also have this problem", which also wouldn't be an appropriate comment.

Comment: thanks for the dupe @fbuekert. Thats a fitting one. The arguments of [THIS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233861/412631) are preudo IMO.

Comment: There's also [Lower the amount of reputation needed to comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/lower-the-amount-of-reputation-needed-to-comment)

Comment: @Dukeling to be fair, I've seen quite a few not-new users who have good answers ask bad questions (I think I've done it myself..)

Comment: Actually "technically strong" might not be relevant at all, to either asking or commenting appropriately. You need to be "Stack Overflow strong", which is something else entirely (although there might be some correlation). You can be the most technically strong person of all time, but you may still not know what comments are for, or which details you should be including in a question. People who are *not* particularly technically strong might actually be able to ask the best questions and leave the best comments, since a wider audience might have similar questions and comments.

Comment: The discussion is becoming off-topic. My idea was to generate a possibility for new users that ARE ABLE to contribute, to contribute.

Comment: @TheWanderer In theory: you need to have interacted with things on the site to gain reputation, thus there's a better chance that you know what those things are supposed to look like the more reputation you have. (this question is more about comments than questions)

Answer (score 10):

New users *can* comment.  On their own posts, and on answers to their questions.  It is prevented everywhere else for a few reasons; one is spam.  Another is confusion; it takes a small amount of investment to understand what the site is for.

> Only experienced users (rep > ~1000 from answering) can see the comment first, no one else can.

So, curators get additional work.  I'd prefer we focus our efforts on more permanent content, like questions and answers.

> We cannot prevent users from posting spam on the site. (They can always use the answer for this.)

No, we can't.  But by posting it as a question or answer, it gets bumped, and therefore gets more eyes on it, getting rid of it quicker.

> We can maximize the contribution by giving the technically strong new users a shot.

Then they can post an answer; there's no rep requirement to contribute to our body of knowledge.

Comment: `to 1.` experienced users read the questions and therefore comments anyways. Up or downvoting comments is faster than flagging answers, also mods are therefore relieved. `to 3.` often issues are solved by comments only. Commenting plays an important role.

Comment: Commenting plays an important role in clarifying a question; that's why we allow it.  If a question isn't clear, there's also the option to move on to another question that *is* clear.  Also, I didn't say mods.  I said curators.  Those of us who invest in the site being better.  There's easily enough work to go around that we don't need to add additional comment judgements into the mix.

Comment: pointing out typos or clerical error in the comments is an often "issue solver". Sure this feature is not super essential but would improve this site IMO.

Comment: If the core of a problem is a typo, it's likely off-topic, and shouldn't be answered; they aren't good questions worth keeping.  Comments are to request clarification, and suggest improvements.  If it solves the issue, it should be an answer, not a comment.