# Is it relevant to ask for multiple reviewers for each edit?

Tags: discussion, edits, moderator-tools

Lately I've noticed this shiny new link in the toolbar: [image]

It's pretty cool that anonymous/low-rep users can now contribute to the quality of Stack Overflow.

However, is it relevant that multiple reviewers are required to validate an edit? I find it weird that the community entrusts me to edit posts, but that my intervention alone isn't enough to propagate someone else's edits. After all, if I like it so much, I can just go make the changes myself.

What do you think about that?

Comment: I've already seen a number of reviews that had 1 accept and 1 reject vote.  The edits were indeed marginal.  So I can definitely see some benefit to requiring two people to approve.

Comment: I thought it was said that there were only two reviewers required on SO post edits, not on all sites. I was under the impression other sites only needed one reviewer to approve. Does that impact this question?

Answer (score 2):

Other side of the medal:

[Abridged too far?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77674/abridged-too-far/77683#77683)