# Edit posts directly vs approving edits

Tags: discussion, edits

What determines what I do, and when?

Sometimes I can edit posts directly, and the changes show up immediately.

Other times, like just now, I "approved" someone's edit, but it needs someone else to also approve the edit.

Why the apparently different levels of oversight on editing?

(If it makes any difference my SO reputation is over 6k.)

Comment: Related: [Abridged too far?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77674/abridged-too-far) (see Jeff's answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [2k rep](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) to edit or to approve edits. 2k users can always edit without approval. Users that have less than 2k rep can suggest edits, but they need to be approved. SO (and only SO, at least for the moment) requires two approvals before the edit goes through -- when it only required one approver a lot of poor edits were getting approved because the approver didn't read it carefully

Comment: I wouldn't say at *any* time. If there is a pending edit, you're only allowed to make judgement on the edit instead of make the modifications yourself. (Or so I'm seeing on the last few posts I've been go over).

Comment: @Brad I didn't say "at any time", but yes, a pending suggested edit blocks further edits