# Calling people "haters" is unwelcoming

Tags: support, blog, sidebar, podcast

There's a podcast linked in the sidebar titled [Podcast 341: Blocking the haters as a service](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/05/25/podcast-341-blocking-the-haters-as-a-service/?cb=1):

[image: "Blocking the haters as a service" in the sidebar]

The Code of Conduct clearly forbids name calling and personal insults:

> **No name-calling or personal attacks.**
>
> Focus on the content, not the person. This includes terms that feel personal even when they're applied to content (e.g. “lazy”).

It goes even further:

> **No subtle put-downs or unfriendly language.**
>
> Even if you don’t intend it, this can have a negative impact on others.

If you really believe in these rules, then it must apply to yourselves, including your blog. Don't be dismissive of other people's feelings, even when they're upset about something that doesn't bother you.

If you don't demonstrate the attitude you require of others, how can you expect others to act according to it?

Comment: eh, i haven't listened to it, but the title seems to just be wordplay (that i agree is unnecessarily divisive) on the topic, which is dealing with harassment. Quite unfortunate for that topic to follow SO recently pushing out a font change where they summarily dismissed people who had/have issues with it.

Comment: @KevinB If referring to someone by a particular word constitutes harassment (or as SO has insisted in some cases, even *not* calling them by a particular word), then plastering name calling on the front page is harassment.

Comment: I'm confused why you think this qualifies as name calling. Haters exist, in the same vein that trolls exist or racists exist. Whatever term you use, it _can be_ used as a form of name calling when directed at someone specific. But when discussing the topic of haters in general, how exactly does it become an attack? We cannot discuss these topics at all because the terms can be negative? How many times has the word "trolls" been brought up here on Meta? Same thing...

Comment: @animuson Let me make sure I understand the implications of what you're saying. As long as an insult refers to no specific person participating in a discussion, it's allowed? Because that would be in direct contradiction of clear SO ruling on some particular issues I can think of.

Comment: @jpmc26 that isn’t name calling (cause there’s nobody specific you’re calling that name) and it isn’t a **personal** attack

Comment: I think you're interpreting that section of the CoC in an invalid way. To use that example. lazy people exist. And there's nothing wrong with discussing "lazy people" in general. Calling a specific person lazy by referring directly to them or their content is inappropriate, though. This is exactly why we have always banned the use of the [specific-user] tag and discourage referencing specific users or posts when bringing up issues on Meta.

Comment: @animuson "And there's nothing wrong with discussing 'lazy people' in general." Why not? Isn't it unwelcoming, particularly to people who might feel it refers to them because their questions have been rejected as inadequate?

Comment: In the case of the blog, "haters" is referring to people who harass other people with hateful speech on sites like Twitter, and I see no problem with referring to some anonymous person who would direct hateful content towards another as a hater. It's an appropriate term for what is being described.

Comment: @animuson Let me clarify a bit. Labeling a group of people "haters" immediately encourages an "us, the good guys, vs. them, the bad guys" mindset. Isn't that sort of division where you're inclined to immediately assume you're in the "good" group something the CoC seeks to discourage? It certainly does not strike me as very kind, respectful, or inclusive, much less patient or welcoming.

Comment: Yes there are groups of people. People who spread hate on purpose do belong to a group, and this group is NOT welcome in Stack Exchange. That's a good thing. If someone will claim *you*, personally, is a "hater" that's name calling and can be reported, but just discussing this in general is **not**.

Comment: Related is the ***consistent*** general hate (e.g., by making fun of) on [COBOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COBOL), [Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl), and [PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) on the podcast (indirectly hating on the practitioners of those languages). Some of it is entirely superficial, like the use of [sigils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_(computer_programming)). All three languages are extremely useful in the real world, outside of the cool kids' New York club.

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard We all hate something and are even spreading hate on purpose. Surely, I am allowed to hate JavaScript ;) I am not really sensitive kind, but I also think using haters in a podcast title is just too raw (I cannot find more appropriate word now)

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard Unfortunately, we live in a world where mere policy disagreement is categorized as "hate." Consider immigration debates, for instance, where wanting to enforce immigration law is categorized as "hate," and the more relevant to our community gender issues, where denying certain truth claims is labeled "hate." Particularly without context (and even in context in this case), how can I trust that this usage refers to *actual* hate vs. this overuse, especially when the speakers in the podcast appear to support to ideology of people who tend to overuse the label?

Comment: @jpmc26 no matter how you spin it around, you're trying to hit SE with their own weapon, in a way that I disagree with. As long as they don't put names and speak about specific people (Yes, **UNLIKE** Monica's case) it is totally fine. If and when they'll do it (again) by all means, raise all possible flags, rally support and bash their walls. I'll be there to help.

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard I'm trying to apply to rules in a consistent manner. SO is not okay with language they consider "unwelcoming" to groups they favor, even when it's not applied to anyone in particular. This is a group you and SO do not favor. The fact you "disagree" with it only indicates that you're not trying to apply the rules in an objective, fair manner based on treating people equally, but instead are trying to demonize groups you dislike and promote groups you like. Which is really the entire point here: inconsistency and a devaluing of people based on your personal opinions.

Comment: @jpmc26 that's right. Back to the beginning, there are unwelcome groups. It is personal opinion. I'm sure there are sites and places where spreading hate and cursing each other is welcome. Stack Exchange isn't such a place, and I'm glad for that. So it is unfair for those who hate and curse? Sure. So what? I'm fine with that. :)

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard 1. A "hater" is not a person spreading hate, even by the moderators' own admissions here. 2. The idea that everyone who disagrees with you about any particular issue is "spreading hate" is itself a prejudice that assumes the correctness of your view. 3. The Code of Conduct does not say anyone is unwelcome. It says everyone is welcome and should feel included. It doesn't matter if you're fine with it. So there's only two options here: the CoC doesn't mean what it says or the policy is not being applied as intended. Which is it?

Comment: 1. So what is a "hater"? 2. I don't think and never said you spread hate. And you disagree with me. So your claim is wrong. 3. It's trivial common sense. You can't write rules for every possible scenario.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree that labeling people instead of their behaviors damages our thinking and leads to "us" needing to fix those problematic "thems", but "You made this rule, you should follow it" isn't the best way to address it. Most of humankind does this sort of labeling instinctively-we even apply some labels to ourselves-and it takes effort to change it. Often our aspirations exceed our ability, so it would be better to explain why this sort of label is a problem and then offer an alternative way to express the idea than it would be to argue about whether or not it violates some rule.

Comment: @ColleenV Been [tried](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342646/1394393) (in many instances with many different problems by many different people beyond just that example). Has no effect.

Comment: @jpmc26 You tried the "beat them over the head with the CoC" approach there also. It doesn't work, especially when emotions are running high. I didn't say it's easy to persuade people to give up labels. Hell, I accept that labels damage my thinking and I still find myself using them sometimes when I shouldn't. I responded to the original "take a stand" post with a similar view and it probably didn't change anyone's mind, but maybe if someone keeps hearing it in a way that doesn't make them want to defend name-calling as not-a big-deal-if-it's-general-enough they'll get there eventually.

Comment: @ColleenV Read the post. I explained in detail *why* the content in question was a problem as you describe. I used the Be Nice rules as a guide because I actually thought they meant something at the time and represented values we could agree on. And then I *begged* for improvements, doing my absolute best to appeal to their better nature. Regardless, many others have used approaches that did not leverage any sort of rules.

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard In practical usage, a "hater" is anyone who speaks an opinion that the speaker wishes to dismiss and deride without having to present an argument against it. For example, when I tried to explain to a superior that database performance tools could not make up for the lack of experience and knowledge among myself and my colleagues and could lead to more problems if we didn't understand what the tool was telling us, he called me a "hater." He did so because he felt personally slighted by my reasoned response, since the tooling was his idea.

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard With regard to spreading hate, I didn't say you said anything in particular. I was emphasizing that you can't equivocate criticism with spreading hate, when often what this issue is really about is ideological criticism. As for rules for every scenario, I'm not suggesting any such thing. The rules spell out a specific set of values as a good thing, and then the company ignored those values. A simple, "You're right. We goofed. We'll fix this," is all that could be expected. In lieu of any action, I'll have to settle for sunlight on the hypocrisy.

Answer (score 22):

Sometimes it's useful not to 'simply' judge a book by its cover - or perhaps a podcast 'simply' by its title. I took a quick look at the [transcripts](https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/tracy-chou-block-party-anti-harassment-tech/transcript)  and the topic of discussion is about a tool that reminds me a *lot* of Smoke Detector for Twitter, and a few other bits of data.

The nice thing about the transcript is that I can do a quick search for the word *haters* and it is said a grand total of zero times. (And I might want to actually listen to it - sounds interesting.)

As for the term itself - as a moderator, and occasional yeller at SE when they mess up, it's useful for me, at least as a mental exercise to consider whether a reasonable person would find it offensive. Naturally, opinions may differ, as does cultural relevance.

The first thing that comes to mind is the term "Haters gonna hate":

[image]

Practically - in modern/internet culture, this tends to be a term used to brush off folks who're trying to put you down, so... for most part it's inoffensive.

The US government (and I assume the current administration) also talks about it in those terms in their [anti-bullying page](https://www.stopbullying.gov/cyberbullying/how-to-deal-with-haters) <sub>[archive link](https://archive.is/haHll)</sub> - using the precise term and defining it as:

> "Hater" is a label used to refer to people who use negative and critical comments and behavior to bring another person down by making them look or feel bad.

I don't find anything specifically relevant in the [current stacks design guide either](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/principles/).

Naturally - it's not for me to say what someone would be offended by, but it feels like it's not *that* offensive a label unless applied to someone specifically.

On the other hand, when talking about tools - [internal](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/04/09/the-unfriendly-robot-automatically-flagging-unwelcoming-comments/), or [community led](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/25/how-does-spam-protection-work-on-stack-exchange/), it's about the tool and objectives, not the 'target'. It *is* a bit unusual, title-wise.

It's certainly a *clickbaity* title, and possibly oversimplifies the work being done by block party, but I wouldn't go as far as escalating it as a COC violation if it had been something I had to moderate based on content alone.

Comment: Personally and this is entirely the reason I downvoted this question and upvoted this answer, when I saw the title of the podcast, immediately took “Haters” as a reference to those who  attempt to claim people cannot do something. Reading as much as I could stomach of the transcript, that’s pretty much the reference, only difference is those “haters” are on Twitter and there is a service to block them. Distasteful title of an episode, perhaps, but nothing insulting to anyone in the SE community

Comment: @Ramhound No, it's not a reference to people claiming someone can't do something. It's a reference to identity focused worldviews, where "hate" can mean anything from actual prejudices to mere political disagreement. You can see that in the transcript, with references to things like "social justice" (or even the vastly more strange "climate justice").

Comment: "'Hater' is a label..." Yeah, exactly. That's the problem. It, as a label, is almost exclusively used to disparage and dismiss people. The podcast itself isn't so... directly demeaning, but that would only be more justification for changing the title.

Comment: Of special irony is the fact that using "hater" in the manner your definition describes would actually qualify the speaker as a "hater." It's a pejorative (which makes it a negative and critical commentary) that's used to make someone look or feel bad, and worse, it's used by the speaker to make themselves feel superior.

Comment: Maybe - but having a point of reference to how it might be used is useful. Of course, unless we can find a neutral point of view to the use of the term. That proved exceedingly difficult

Comment: I wasn't objecting to the inclusion of the definition. I was saying that even the definition you found supports my point and undermines yours.

Comment: Ah, but you're assuming I fundamentally disagree - I am not. I'm critically assessing the broader situation. I don't think its a *great* title, but the COC isn't the right tool in this instance IMO.  And I guess - how *inaccurate* would the title be for a podcast for tools that block negative and critical comments? Could there be a better option?  And more importantly - how we can get more considered titles....

Comment: @jpmc26 - You can’t tell me how I took the title is incorrect; While I might not agree with the podcast content or the subject matter, and I might agree the title of the episode is distasteful, I am not offended by the title itself and understand its reference. I personally hated Twitter and Facebook before the last year, I certainly hate them even more, given their recent policy choices.

Comment: bonus points for the panda

Comment: See the edit. The CoC is clearly written to be generally opposed to any kind of downputting language.

Answer (score 10):

Humans categorize in order to more easily address specific things.
In this context, 'haters' simply refers to those users who (actively) participate in "*online harassment*" (quoted from the link you posted).
The word 'hate' has a negative connotation, and that may be why you interpret it as name-calling.

Also keep in mind that *no individuals* are addressed here: **this is an abstraction, a label** used for a threat to this community.
It is similar to using the word 'misogynists', 'racists' - as well as 'philanthropists' or 'patrons' - in order to talk about a specific group of people whose actions (and often convictions) have a specific influence on or consequence for those using these labels (or the ones they care about).

---

A more objective argument: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/hater) defines 'hater' as

> A person who greatly dislikes a specified person or thing.
>
> - *informal* A negative or critical person.

There is nothing inherently insulting about the word.

Comment: "There is nothing inherently insulting about the word." I'm sorry, but that's nonsense. It is absolutely an insult, used to be intentionally dismissive of someone and anything they have to say. And the use of "misogynists" and "racists" is also unwelcoming, not because actual prejudices are good, but because the labels are applied so broadly today that they can encompass anyone. (There are literally people who claim that having a specific skin color makes you inherently racist.) They're far more often hurled as insults than as specific terms, and "hater" is no different in that regard.

Comment: @jpmc26 I think you mistake 'insult' for '(potentially) hurtful'.

Comment: The CoC goes so far as to forbid unintentional unfriendly language, so even if you were correct, that distinction would be meaningless here. You're not correct, though. It is absolutely a word used to intentionally put someone down.

Answer (score 10):

Whether or not calling people haters is unwelcoming and a CoC violation... it's meh, it depends *mostly* on a context that apparently isn't shared by everyone here. I've seen the word "haters" used in so many contexts online that it can be basically anything from a joking insult for people that don't like pineapple on pizza to a word used to dismiss things that you don't want to listen to. Some usage of it is fun, some usage of it is 'clinical' (following a 'dictionary definition'), some usage of it is dismissive.

This whole post (question, answers, comments) reminds me of a post on IPS Meta, where [one of the answers](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1389/1599) made a good point:

> You may have intended to communicate these concerns via the term "militant", but all you're really conveying is your own perception of this person; if we were sitting down over a pitcher of beer and plate of nachos such a description would aid in commiseration with you, but does little to help further our understanding of the person that you wish to communicate with.

In this case: **all this post, and the reactions here, are conveying is our own perception of this word**.

Personally, I wouldn't reach for labelling the use of the word haters in this instance a Code of Conduct violation (because I perceive a different intent behind the use of this word in a podcast title), but I would agree that the title could've been more clear by using e.g. 'online harassment' instead of 'haters', in order to avoid all these perceptions.

Comment: The semantics of a word being offensive or inadequate are not only subjective perception (as your bold categorically states). Otherwise there would be no offensive vocabulary mentioned in the CoC. Besides, SE has made poor choices both in wording and concept see [Why is SO running a promoted tweet with scaremongering Wikipedia misinformation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401137), [turd polishing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77683) to name only a few.

Comment: @bad_coder I don't see me claiming anywhere that the semantics of a word being offensive or inadequate are *only* subjective perception. I don't see the word *only* in my bolded sentence anywhere, and I'm well aware that such perceptions are steered by e.g. processes of [pejoration and melioration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pejorative#Pejoration_and_melioration) and/or the community/context these words are used in (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigga).

Comment: Still, if you want to argue the point, I'd say that "offensive vocabulary" as listed in the CoC *is* subjective perception, enforcing the same 'offensive vocabulary' rule on e.g. Parler would lead to different results, because of different perceptions of different words.  Otherwise, why mention 'offensive vocabulary' in the CoC at all? Just give us poor mods a list of words we can delete on sight, and if it's not there, we don't need to moderate it. But because of the above, that's just not going to happen, and what is/isn't offensive is left up to the community and mods to decide.

Comment: *"I've seen the word "haters" used in so many contexts online that it can be basically anything from a joking insult for people that don't like pineapple on pizza to a word used to dismiss things that you don't want to listen to."* - +1, basically what [I said about ambiguity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364816/calling-people-haters-is-unwelcoming/364818#comment1217670_364816)

Comment: Can you think of any instance in which the word "haters" was not used in a manner intended to be dismissive of someone? To deride their thoughts and opinions? Even your "pineapple on pizza" example is still doing that to some group of people.

Comment: @jpmc26 Congrats, you reconfirmed the point: not all context is shared by everyone and as such our perceptions are colored differently. Yes, I can think of instances where 'haters' wasn't used with the intent to be dismissive of someone, but where the intent was to acknowledge an agreement to disagree and full acceptance of differences to the point where two people are comfortable joking about those. Whether that's about pineapple on pizza or applying mascara before or after eye-shadow, the context is there for me. Apparently not for you though, so any example I give would be useless to you.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell That's an interesting response because the CoC addresses it: "Be inclusive and respectful. Avoid sarcasm and be careful with jokes — tone is hard to decipher online." So the usage you described is explicitly discouraged by the CoC.

Comment: @Jpmc26 Discouraging something is different from telling people to be careful when using something. I've never been discouraged from using sharp knives to cut up vegetables, but I have been told to be careful when using sharp knives. Perhaps you could say I have been discouraged to not go waving around sharp knives wildly as part of being careful with knives, but again, that doesn't mean I'm being discouraged from using those sharp knives entirely. So what's explicitly discouraged here can be argued about, which isn't something I'm all that interested in to be honest.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Plastering something commonly used as an insult on the site's functional homepage certainly doesn't qualify as "careful." It's about as careful as throwing the knife at the vegetable in a crowded room.

Comment: @jpmc26 'Avoid sarcasm and be careful with jokes' is hating the British, (or, at least, some kind of woke argument could be made for that:).

Comment: @MartinJames I am no Brit, but I grew up on British humor... I have hard time adjusting to that requirement. I mean how can people even live without joking all the time ;)

Answer (score -1):

It's fine. I'm a hater of some things. I don't see it as a pejorative. Labelling me a hater doesn't pit me against anyone; it just describes my attitude (in a playful, well-known, idiomatic way). And if they mean it in a more specific way (e.g. "people who harass other people with hateful speech"), then I'm also fine, because it doesn't apply to me, I hope!

Comment: It's good that you're fine, and if the company based their policy around responding with charity to such things, I wouldn't be posting this. That is not the nature of the policy.

Comment: Thanks! I made it community wiki so you can improve it.

Comment: Don't make it community wiki, that's not what it's meant for. (downvote shield.)

Comment: What is that? I see 4 downvotes. It can be edited *or* downvoted.

Comment: I tried to make it community wiki, but it isn't permanent. I think you can still make edits though.